# Wait for thread-signals in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, events, signals

First of all: this question is **NOT** about the normal Qt-signals which notify e.g. when a button was clicked. What I'm looking for is a signal mechanism where one thread sends a signal while an other one is waiting for it (such as SetEvent()/WaitForSingleObject() when using WinAPI).

So my question: is there such a mechanism available in Qt? If yes: what class/function provides this?

thanks!

Comment: In C++, this could be done with [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). Because, most things of `std` have a "Qt native" thing, I googled for "Qt condition" and found [Wait Conditions Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-waitconditions-example.html). Sounds promising... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff looks good, thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [Qt Thread Synchronization](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html)?